# Optimising / minimizing a local copy of the DB table using python (Currently using Pickle)

Tags: python, postgresql, serialization, pickle

I am establishing a connection to a DB hosted on RedShift and want to save the table locally as a `pickle file` (or any other way) to save time.

When I am saving **100k records**, it's taking **163 MBs** of space and the total number of records **~ 14 million**, so it would take around **165 GBs** for the entire table.

Whereas one of my colleagues saved the table as `.rds` file through `R` and it only took **~500 MBs** for the entire 14 million records.

How can I save space and make things faster in python? Why is rds format taking such low space?

Here's a sample of my code (Using Python 2.7.11, cPickle, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

```
def write_pickle(folder, filename, my_obj, overwrite = False):
    filepath = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    if overwrite:
        print('Writing into pickle file...')
        with gzip.open(filepath, 'wb') as handle:
            pickle.dump(my_obj, handle, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    else:
        if os.path.isfile(filepath) == False:
            print('Writing into pickle file...')
            with gzip.open(filepath, 'wb') as handle:
                pickle.dump(my_obj, handle, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

connection_obj = form_connection_obj()
cursor = connection_obj.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT TOP 100000 * FROM my_dataset;')

write_pickle('folder', 'filename.p', list(cursor.fetchall()))
```

**UPDATE 1:** After converting to `cPickle` from `pickle` and using the `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` the size reduced to half (~83 MBs for 100k records) but it is still very large compared to the `R` counterpart.

**UPDATE 2:** After using `gzip` the size was reduced (~17 MB for 100k records) but it is still more than 3 times R's `.rds` format and slower too.

This question would be **little different to the one suggested** since

1) I am not fixated on using pickle, I just want to have a local dump of data to avoid remote DB connection everytime.

2) I want to find the best way to do this (it may not even involve dumping the table locally).

3) Solution suggested in the other question using `gzip` has made loading the pickle considerably slow.

Comment: What protocol of pickle are you using? What is your python version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decreasing the size of cPickle objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474791/decreasing-the-size-of-cpickle-objects)

Comment: I am on Python 3.5.2.
Could be a possible duplicate but never got that search result. Strange!!

By how much would zipping compress the data?

Comment: Have you tried to compress the file after the pickling (with bz2, gzip or lzma)?

Comment: Yes, I tried `gzip`.It produced a ~17 MB file for 100k records but the loading was so slow that I might as well fetch the 100k records every time.

Comment: @S.deMelo I am using `2.7.11`. By mistake, I mentioned my local development version