# Reduce Python shelve size

Tags: python, pickle, shelve

I'm using the 
[shelve module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#restrictions) with [gdbm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gdbm.html) to store Python objects. I understand that `shelve` uses `pickle` to store the objects. Unfortunately, the sizes of my shelves are too large. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474791/decreasing-the-size-of-cpickle-objects) solution to `bzip2` or `gzip` individual pickles. My question is: is there a way to make `shelve` compress all its pickles?

Comment: if all your files are in the same directory just do `gzip *` from the CLI

Comment: @aws_apprentice the problem is that I would need to access shelve entries individually.

Comment: so? it will zip each one separately

Comment: Shelf is a single file containing many pickled objects.