# How to save all python objects from working directory to a file

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find the way to save all objects (or at least dataframes) to one place, outside of working directory. I assume Python keeps all objects in memory not on disk, so I'm looking for the way of exporting all objects from current session. It can be pickle, does not matter until you can read it to a different Python session

Comment: This seems not duplicated. The questions search for a way to backup a whole session. The linked answer only address how to save an object via `pickle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your need, you want to backup your session.
If that is the case, here is a solution using `pickle`. Kr.

***First solution is***:

```
import pickle

def is_picklable(obj):
    try:
        pickle.dumps(obj)
    except Exception:
        return False
    return True

bk = {}
for k in dir():
    obj =  globals()[k]
    if is_picklable(obj):
        try:
            bk.update({k: obj})
        except TypeError:
            pass

# to save session
with open('./your_bk.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(bk, f)

    
# to load your session

with open('./your_bk.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    bk_restore = pickle.load(f)
```

***Second solution is with `dill`. You might have error if in your workspace, there are some unpicklable objects ***:

```
import dill

dill.dump_session('./your_bk_dill.pkl')
#to restore session:
dill.load_session('./your_bk_dill.pkl')
```

***Third option go with `shelve` package***:

```
import shelve

bk = shelve.open('./your_bk_shelve.pkl','n')
for k in dir():
    try:
        bk[k] = globals()[k]
    except Exception:
        pass
bk.close()

# to restore
bk_restore = shelve.open('./your_bk_shelve.pkl')
for k in bk_restore:
    globals()[k]=bk_restore[k]
    tmp[k] = bk_restore[k]
bk_restore.close()
```

Check and let's know about your trial.

Credits: The second and third solution are nearly a shameless copy/paste from those two links belows. I adapted the handling of errors as the original answer will lead to error for pickling of module.
[dill solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872056/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-pickleable)
[shelve solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960864/how-to-save-all-the-variables-in-the-current-python-session)

Comment: I checked `dill` module and `shelve`. `Dill` suits me best as `shelve` doesn't dump DataFrame object.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. `Dill` indeed is more versatile. In my hand, a small toy dataframe can be pickled though. May be your dataframe contains something more complex?

Comment: Also, a good point of `Shelve` is quite effective in memory saving (not load all variables back at once if not needed). If you have time, here is my [small post](https://antrg.medium.com/python-for-datascientist-quick-backup-for-everything-6d201a7e935d) on the subjet.

Comment: I take back my words. I can not backup session as `dill.dump_session` returns `TypeError: can't pickle _gdbm.gdbm objects`. The session was restored from `shelve` backup. One disadvantage of `shelve` is that you cannot compress it [Reduce Python shelve size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53990501/14261102)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a dataframe in another directory, try :

```
df.to_csv('foldername/filename.csv')
```